# Add neighboors from matrix without diagonals

Tags: java

I'm trying to add the neighbors of a x position in a matrix[3][3] and I want to do it in an efficient way. Currently, I can add all of the neighbors, but I want to only add the neighbors at the top,down,left,right. What is wrong with my code?

```
for(int i=line-1;i<=line+1;i++)
{
    for(int j=col-1;j<=col+1;j++)
    {
        int[][] matrixAux = this.matrix;
        if(i<3 && j<3 && i>=0 && j>=0)
        {

       //then add neighbor

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There's no need for a loop to be involved in adding up neighbors of a specific position.

Answer (score 0):

You're approach is simply based on a too complex idea. Try something more trivial:

```
int upper = matrix[i + 1][j];
int lower = matrix[i - 1][j];
int left = matrix[i][j - 1];
int right = matrix[i][j + 1];

add(upper , lower , left , right);
```

It's hard to produce any code that shows how to use this without any information how your code should work and what it's used for, but I hope this clarifies the idea.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

Let me explain better.

Matrix 

5 6 3
1 0 5
2 6 4

For example, for matrix 1 I want to add the neighboors of 0 (up,down,left,right) and save the resultant matrix for each one of the neighbors. (Later I'll do a depthfirst search).

Comment: @CarlosBernardes the only reason, why a bit more code from your side would've been useful is to include my suggested code, to make it better understandable. Anyways, I hope this answers the question?